# Picasso Library Load Error

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using the `Picasso` library to dynamically load images from an API call.

Certain urls seem to return a malformed URL, for example: `"http://imagesite.com/image.1241123.gif` which crashes the app.

```
  Picasso.with(activity).load(image)
.centerCrop()
    .error(R.drawable.icon01)
    .resize(50, 50)
    .into(icon);
```

Looking at the documentation, I assumed the `.error()` parameter would handle this, but `Picasso` seems to see it as a valid URL, even though it won't return an image. I've also tried using the `Picasso.Builder` but I continue to get the same errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an invalid URL...! It should be imagesite.com/, imagesite.net/ etc

Comment: And also I dont find a gif file on the given link

Comment: Its 404 error...! file not found

Comment: @ArsalImam yes, that's just an example to show the format of the URL that's causing problems. Using that url in picasso gives me the same error as the one from the api call. I used it to replicate the issue, which leads me to think it's something to do with the url format

Answer (score 1):

picasso don't load gif image for that you have to use Glide library.
Check this link it might help you : http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

and you get library from : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

`error()` will handle issues where the URL is well formed but for some reasons it cannot display the image.

If you have malformed url it means the problem is your data. Remember garbage in , garbage out.

Use `Uri.parse()` before loading it to picasso, then handle the thrown exception: better fix your data.